# Can we call a javascript function from an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod, client-side-scripting

I have created a web method, and accessing it through ajax call, 
And I wanted to randomly run any client side script from ajax.

Is such scenario possible or do I need to return some flag parameter from ajax call and run any script on the basis of returned flag parameter`s inside Ajax Success?

Please suggest a better approach or solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question doesnt make much sense, if you want to run a javascript function before an ajax call, then do it, if you want to run it after the ajax call is complete do it in a success callback/promise chain. It makes no sense to run a javascript call "from" an ajax call.

Comment: You can return javascript from your server and then run it in the browser using `eval`. However, this is a huge security hole. It would be much better to return a parameter that is used within the success function to call a method.

Comment: get the return value(flag parameter) from webmethod and call script in success value of ajax method.

Comment: what did u tried can u post ur code??

Comment: Thank you so much folks. I found my approach was wrong to solve an issue. Appreciate your response.